# Stm8l mcu RTC calibration problem using RTC_SmoothCalibConfig()

Tags: stm32, calibration, real-time-clock, stm8

stm8l151k4 mcu

`rtc` external crystal works stably but returns error when I want to write calibration value.

```
"RTC_SmoothCalibConfig(RTC_SmoothCalibPeriod_32sec, RTC_SmoothCalibPlusPulses_Reset,50);"
```

When I looked at the bit causing the error, I saw that the `RECALPF` bit did not return to 0 in any way

also I am using iar stm8 compiler it does not show `RTC_CALRH` and `RTC_CALRL` registers in debug mode.

Note reference manual
"This register cannot be written when `RTC_ISR1/RECALPF` is set to 1 (see: Instant recalibration."

```
RTC_SmoothCalibConfig(RTC_SmoothCalibPeriod_32sec, RTC_SmoothCalibPlusPulses_Reset,50);
```

Comment: I've removed one of your weird tags. I've left #stm32, even although it is irrelevant, only because it's probably the only way anyone will see this question. It should be removed if you get an answer though.